# Mapping repeat last command

Tags: key-bindings, substitute, repeated-commands

Apologies I am probably expressing myself very badly, that's also why 1 hour searching hasn't yielded the result I wanted yet...

Assume I want to replace `true` with `false` in a buffer.

`:s/true/false`

Now, this is such a common word that I don't want to just change globally `:%s/true/false/g`. I want to move the cursor (or search for the word), and every time I want to actually change, repeat the substitution.

So I can do then
`:<up arrow to show again the substitution command><CR>`

If I'd like to map this to a keyboard shortcut:

`map <C-Y> :<WHAT TO PUT HERE?><CR>`  ?

I tried `map <C-Y> :@<CR>` but that doesn't seem to be doing what I want.

Answer (score 3):

No mapping necessary!

Vim has the [`&` command](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%26) which just repeats the last substitution. The same way as `.` repeats the last command, I can move to the next `true` and simply hit `&` which will apply again the last substitution. Neat and simple.

I found out by googling “vi repeat last substitution”
which yielded [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/382155/9447571) as the first result.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In specific, you don't need to go into details on which keywords led you to the answer... Just explain what it is that works to resolve your problem. Feel free to keep the reference to the Stack Overflow answer that helped you (but I suggest moving it to the end of the answer, as it's not really the most important part...)